# adding latex packages to doxygen can not work

Tags: latex, doxygen

I want to add some graphics to my doxygen generated output. For that I need to add some more packages:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows}
```

The first two lines can be added to the `Doxyfile` with

```
EXTRA_PACKAGES         = {tikz} \
                         {tikz-qtree}
```

But the 2 other ones are not.

Is there a chance to add a `.tex` file into the generated output files before `pdflatex` starts?

Adding

```
LATEX_EXTRA_STYLESHEET = packages.tex
```

will not work. It used my file but the output is broken. Seems that the packages are loaded at the wrong place or time.

The third thing i tried was writing a header file with

```
doxygen -w latex ....
```

This works and changing the header.tex file is ok, but this ends up in always in generating the header, patching the header, run doxygen again with own header. This is very stupid!

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

The `EXTRA_PACKAGES` option is equivalent to the `\usepackage` tag in Latex. This of course doesn't work for the `\usetikzlibrary` tags.
You can add your modified Latex header using the tag `LATEX_HEADER` in the Doxyfile, e.g.:

```
LATEX_HEADER = ./templates/latex/YourCustomHeader.tex
```

Then Doxygen pulls this Latex header file when generating the documentation. In this file you can add the used packages and libraries.

By the way: The custom stylesheet isn't used before you run the make.bat script, so it is sufficient if you copy the modified 'doxygen.sty' file to the output folder after Doxygen generated the Latex files, but before you run the 'make.bat' script to generate the PDF file. I do this by a script which first calls doxygen then copies the necessary files to the output folder and finally calls the 'make.bat' script...

Comment: The "solution" with `LATEX_HEADER` was already mentioned in my question. As already noted, it needs further scripting because the first page of the document is generated in this header file. So it still is boring to work this way, because you have to generate the header file `doxygen -w` and patch the file for each document you want to generate. Not very nice...